# Potential energy separately for each object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, potential-energy

Potential energy change is :
$\Delta U = -W_{int}$ where $W_{int}$ is the internal forces.

For the ball which is falling down towards earth, we can write:

$\Delta U = -(W_{earth} + W_{ball}) = -(K_{ball} + K_{earth})$

I know potential energy is associated with the interaction of objects, in our example, it's between earth and ball. What I'm trying to understand is only ball has the potential energy or also earth has it ? we often say since ball is in the air, work was done on it, so it gained potential energy which presumes only ball has it.

but imagine 2 particles where they attract each other. do Both particles have the PE ? and is it the same for both ? can it be shown with the formula proof that both particles PE is the same - but this should cause 2 times more energy in the system which I don't believe is true, but I've seen that people say when particle changes location in relative to another particle, its PE changes which presumes I could change location now of another particle and its PE would do the same - so each of them should have PE ? but i know there's only one potential energy for 2 objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know potential energy is associated with the interaction of objects, in our example, it's between earth and ball. What I'm trying to understand is only ball has the potential energy or also earth has it ?

Neither. The potential energy belongs to the system of the earth and the ball together, not to either one separately.

> imagine 2 particles where they attract each other. do Both particles have the PE ? and is it the same for both ? can it be shown with the formula proof that both particles PE is the same - but this should cause 2 times more energy in the system which I don't believe is true

This is one reason why the potential energy must belong to the system and not to the individual parts. Either particle can gain all the energy, but not both.

> people say when particle changes location in relative to another particle, its PE changes

Yes. This is unfortunately common sloppy language. They should say that when a particle changes location the PE of the corresponding system changes.

Comment: Good answer. Though, in ball-earth example, when we say: system has some PE, where did this energy come from if neither ball has it nor earth ? is this energy in space ? also when you lift something in air, you increase PE of the system, but I only acted on the ball, my "work" has been transfered into lifting the ball - hence in the ball. so why not say ball has this PE ?

Comment: @ZazaOrji You may use a model that assigns the potential energy to the ball for the ball-Earth system. But what if you have two balls connected by a spring?

Comment: @ZazaOrji asked “is this energy in space ?” It is in the gravitational field. For the earth and the ball you can assign the energy to the ball but only in the rest frame of the earth and only because the ball’s mass is negligible compared to the earth’s. If either of those conditions are violated it doesn’t work any more

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with teaching of gravitational potential energy is that often the system first considered is the Earth (mass $m_{\rm e}$) and ball (mass $m_{\rm b}$) system.

If there are no external forces acting on the system then the position of the centre of mass of the system does not change.

If distances are measured from the centre of mass of the system to the centres of mass of the Earth and the ball then $m_{\rm e}\,d_{\rm e} = m_{\rm b}\,d_{\rm b}$.
If the ball changes position relative to the centre of mass of the system by $\delta d_{\rm b}$ and consequently the Earth changes position by $\delta d_{\rm e}$ then, $m_{\rm e}\,(d_{\rm e}+\delta d_{\rm e}) = m_{\rm b}\,(d_{\rm b}+\delta d_{\rm b})$ hence, $m_{\rm e}\,\delta d_{\rm e} = m_{\rm b}\,\delta d_{\rm b}$.

The mass of the Earth is approximately $10^{25}\,\rm kg$ so if the ball has a mass of $1\,\rm kg$ you will note that if the ball moves $1\,\rm m$ relative to the centre of mass of the system the Earth moves $10^{-25}\,\rm m$.

Assuming the same magnitude internal forces (Newton's third law), $F\approx 10\, \rm N$, acting on the Earth and the ball then the work done on the ball is $10^{25}$ times larger than the work done on the Earth.
In effect the work done on the Earth by the internal force is negligible as compared to the work done on the ball and the change in separation of the two is effectively $1\rm m$.
Thus, the change in potential energy of the system is just the work done on the ball by the internal force acting on it to a very good approximation with the energy stored in the gravitational field.

Often, how is this topic first taught?
The motion of the Earth is ignored and instead of talking about the potential energy of the Earth and ball system, the potential energy is associated with the ball alone as it is "seen" that the ball alone moves.

The OP has quite rightly noted that if there is not this disparity in the masses of the two particles which form a system then the displacements of the masses are no longer massively different and hence the work done by internal forces on the masses are also relatively significant.
Thus the change in the potential energy of the system is now the sum of the work done on each of the two masses and the movement of both contribute to the change in the potential energy.